# If final vowel in item in list

Tags: python

I have a function: plural(words)

I takes a list of words in base form and then return them in plural form. The rule is that if the final vowel in the word is 'a' or 'o' the plural form is word + 'las' and if the final vowel is 'e' or 'i' the plural form is word + 'les'.

So basically

```
for word in words:
    if #final vowel# in word is 'a' or 'o'
         lst.append(word + 'las')
```

How would I write that as a working code in python? Do I somehow use index or rfind?

Comment: We aren't going to do your homework for you, but here is a hint: you could start by writing a function, `vowels(word)` which, when given a word, returns a list of the vowels in the word in the order in which they appear.

Comment: I thought you meant if the final letter was a vowel. So what I did would not work

Comment: @JohnColeman Update: turns out we did do their homework for them :)

Comment: Don't even need an `if`. Check this out: `for word in words: lst.append(word + ['', '', 'les', 'las'][(word[-1] in 'ao') + (word[-1] in 'aoei') + (word[-1] in 'aoeiu')])`

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterating through your array backwards to find the last vowel.

```
for word in words:
    for letter in reversed(word):
        if letter in vowels_ao: #vowels_ao can be a pre-defined array = ["a", "o"] 
           lst.append(word+"las")
           break
        elif letter in vowels_ei: #same concept
           lst.append(word+"les")
           break
#anything else you want to do
return lst
```

If I understand you question correctly, then that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
length=len(word)
end=word.read(length)
word=read.word(0,(length-1))
If end=='a' OR 'o':
    word.append('las')
```

Maybe that will work?